# Getting the Maven build failure at JaxRS dependency updated the dependency and still getting the issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, jackson, maven-bundle-plugin

Hi Please help me to resolve the below issue.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:377)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
```

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/konteja/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedMember.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember: file:/C:/Users/konteja/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated: file:/C:/Users/konteja/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember

Comment: Please help as i need to close it in urgent basis

Comment: Did you update your Jackson versions? Make sure that all Jackson dependencies use the same version.

Comment: Asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71061403/getting-maven-build-failures-while-clean-and-install-of-my-project) without providing additinal information isn't going to get you an answer.